# How to make a view visible from a dim background

Tags: android, android-layout, opacity, alpha

I have a chat list, which is a ListView. When user want's to copy a message and long holds the chat bubble, the background is dimmed and the chat bubble is highlighted again.

I have put a ListView and a View for the dim background in a FrameLayout. When user long hold the chat bubble I set the listview to a background color of #33617077 with opacity 20%. Is there a way I can remove the dim background color only for the chat bubble so it appears highlighted. I tried setting alpha for the chat bubble to 0.0f but it did not make it transparent. Basically whatever the background of the chat bubble should be visible when long hold pressed.

Here is how it should look[image]:

```
 chatList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {                

    dimLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.dim_color));
    Log.v("long clicked", "pos: " + pos);
    arg1.setAlpha(0.0f);
    arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_message_left);
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Simply set like : `setBackground="#55000000"`

Comment: @DineshShingadiya I want to make it white like above not dark background

Comment: The chat bubble can be of different colors, when long hold the whole screen is dimmed and I want the chat bubble to just appear as before i.e whatever background was set to it before making it dim. So it appears as if its highlighted

Comment: @famfamfam: no but what I did was take a screenshot of the view and place it on the x,y co-ordinates on the view that is dimmed.